# pupeteer function not returning array

Tags: puppeteer

Hi Guys can you please point my mistake on this code?
console.log(urls) is printing undefined.
Thanks in advance.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function GetUrls() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { headless: false,
executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe' })
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://some page");
await page.waitForSelector('a.review.exclick');
        let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let results = [];
            let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.review.exclick');
            items.forEach((item) => {
                results.push({
                    url: item.getAttribute('href'),
                });
            });
            return results;
            browser.close();
             });
}

(async () => {
let URLS = await GetUrls();
console.log(URLS);
process.exit(1);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list:

- you don't have a return statement in your `GetUrls()` function
- you close the browser after a return statement AND inside the `page.evaluate()` method

Keep in mind that anything that is executed within the `page.evaluate()` will relate to the browser context. To quickly test this, add a `console.log("test")` before `let results = [];` and you will notice that nothing appears in your Node.js console, it will appear in your browser console instead.

Therefore, the browser variable is visible within the `GetUrls()` function but NOT visible within the `page.evaluate()` method.

Here is the corrected code sample:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function GetUrls() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://some page");
    await page.waitForSelector('a.review.exclick');
    let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let results = [];
        let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.review.exclick');
        items.forEach((item) => {
            results.push({
                url: item.getAttribute('href'),
            });
        });
        return results;
    });
    await browser.close();
    return urls;
}

(async () => {
    let URLS = await GetUrls();
    console.log(URLS);
    process.exit(1);
})();
```